# VB6のプロジェクトをVS2008で開いた際の作図関係関数のエラーについて

Tags: vb.net

VB6のプロジェクトファイルをVS2008で開くと、slnファイルを生成します。
その際、画像処理関係の次のメンバー関数でエラーが出ます。

```
Cls,ScaleWidth,ScaleHeight,DrawWidth,Scale,FillStyle,FillColor,Circle,Line,PSet,Print,CurrentX,CurrentY
```

具体的には下記の処理をしています。
作図関係処理は「Module1.vb」に記載しており、
「プロジェクト」→「追加」→「標準モジュール」としています。

色々試してみましたが自己解決できませんでした。
ご知見を頂けますと有難く存じます。

```
Form1.PicBox(PicNum).Cls()

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).ScaleWidth = Xmax * Size

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).ScaleHeight = Xmax * Size

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).DrawWidth = 3

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).Scale (PicX1, PicY1) - (PicX2, PicY2)

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).FillStyle = 0

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).FillColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).Circle (XN(I), YN(I)), 0.1, System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).Line(XN(I) - 0.6, YN(I)) - (XN(I) + 0.6, YN(I) - 0.3), QBColor(1), BF

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).PSet (XN(I), YN(I)), System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).Print("No" & I)

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).Line (XN(I), YN(I)) - (XN(I) + 0.2, YN(I) - 0.2 * System.Math.Sqrt(3)), System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Blue)

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).CurrentX = (NX1 + NX2) / 2

Form1.PicBox(PicNum).CurrentY = (NY1 + NY2) / 2
```

Comment: Microsoftのサイトから入手できる[Visual Basic 6.0ユーザーのためのVisual Basic .NET移行ガイド](https://download.microsoft.com/download/VisualStudioNET/Utility/1.0/NT45XP/JA/vbtransitionguide.pdf)のPDFメニュー上の78ページ「第5章 スムーズな移行のためのポイント～フォームとコントロール編～」あたりの記述がヒントになるのでは？

Comment: 「記書き」は "記" の後に箇条書きが原則のようなので、使い方が間違っていると思います。("記" は不要だと思います) https://www.mdsol.co.jp/column/column_122_787.html

Comment: 他にこんな記事 [VB6からVB.NETへの変換について](https://qiita.com/tfukumori/items/9eab7be817eb16992c36) とか、こんな(商業?)サイト [VB Migration Partner](https://www.vbmigration.com/) があるようですので参考になるかも。

Comment: kunif様、情報提供ありがとうございます。資料を勉強して、修正作業をしてみたいと思います。

Comment: 数百本のVB6プログラムの.NET化みたいな案件やった事ありますが、基本的にVB6のソースをコンバートしたところで、そのままでは使い物にならず、変換してエラーだけちょこっと直して解決、というものではありません。足りない処理をラッパークラスや拡張メソッド等で色々自作したりする必要があります。また、.NETに無いコンポーネントが使用されていたりすると、元ソースと見比べたりして処理を解析しながら意図を汲みとりつつ処理を置き換えないといけない事もあり、一筋縄では行かないでしょう。モノによっては、仕様だけ確認して.NETで新規で作り直した方が早い事もあります。

Comment: radian様、アドバイス有難うございます。上手くいかなかった場合は、作図処理だけ.NETで新規に作ることも検討してみます。